# Updating Map Location with Button

Tags: swift, location

I have a view controller that contains a map view and a button that I want to be able to press and update the current location. I am also trying to take that newly updated location (longitude and latitude) and update two columns in a database. I have created a PHP script that I know for a fact works (I've tested it), but I am having trouble combining everything with an IB action. The code below is taken from my viewcontroller.swift file. When I build and run on the simulator, nothing is updated in the database.

```
let loccationManager = CLLocationManager()
var latitude = 0.0
var longitude = 0.0

@IBAction func updateMap(sender: AnyObject) {
    loccationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    print(latitude)
    print(longitude)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last

    latitude = (location?.coordinate.latitude)!
    longitude = (location?.coordinate.longitude)!

}
```

Comment: Why do you have `didUpdateLocations` within your `IBAction`? You could simply create a function which retrieves the current location on tap and returns a `lat`and `lng` which can be used for your `HTTPRequest`

Comment: I inserted `didUpdateLocations` within my IBAction because that's how I assumed I would be able to get the most recent coordinates (`lat` and `lng`).

Comment: A function within another will not be executed.

Comment: I never knew that, thank you

Comment: Best option is to update your location variables when location is updated. (Declare variables outside your function) or creating a function which retrieves the updated the location and returns it (this can be called within your ibaction)

Comment: I declared and initialized `lat` and `long` outside of the function, I also made an instance of `CLLocationManager()`. Inside of `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` I declared `let location = locations.last` and I assigned both `lat` and `long` like this `(location?.coordinate.latitude)!` but when I try to print those two variables during the button click action event, they print as 0.0 (The value I initialized them as)

Comment: Could you update your answer to reflect these recent changes?

Comment: Yes sir, I just updated the code snippet above

Comment: Try calling `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` in your `IBAction`

Comment: I modified my question to include your advice, but unfortunately the issue still persists

Comment: Put `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` in your `updateMap` function, before you try the `lat` and `lng`

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect that change and the output is still 0.0